# Prove that the linear transformation $T : U \rightarrow U$ such that $T \circ T = T$ is one to one.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $U$ be a vector space and $T : U \rightarrow U$ a linear transformation such that $T \circ T = T$. Prove T(u) = T(v) implies u = v for all u, v in $U$. That is, $T$ in one to one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true.  Trivial counterexample: $T=0$.  Less trivial: a projection.